# Safe way to convert string literal without using Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to parse a string literal that contains an environmental variable without using Invoke-Expression?  The string contents come from an external settings file and I want to minimize the possibility of an injection attack.

```
$string= '${env:USERPROFILE}\sub-directory'
# desired result: C:\Users\Name\sub-directory

Invoke-Expression ("Convert-Path " + $string) -OutVariable parsedString
```

Comment: @Matt $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($string) is exactly what I was looking for - many thanks!

Comment: No problem. It is the one I use much of the time.